# What is the most efficient way to verify Variables in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, validation, get, micro-optimization

I'm thinking about an application which recieves massive Data from the User.
But this data has to be verified in php:

f.e. $_GET['id'] has to be a number every Element of an array must be a value between a specific range.

so how efficient are functions like `is_int($x)` or `isset($x)` ? 
Maybe if($x!=null) is faster or (int) x is causing same results.

What is the best way to handle Data that needs to get to Database quick but needs to be verified? Is there any difference in $_GET and $_POST in speed?

Maybe implementing a class doing that improves something?

Maybe for an more concret chance to answer, here a bit inefficent code:

```
if(isset($_GET["x"]) && $_GET["x"] > 0) { $x = $_GET["x"]; }
if(isset($_GET["y"]) && $_GET["y"] > 0) { $y = $_GET["y"]; }
if(isset($_GET["winWidth"]) && $_GET["winWidth"] > 0) {  $winWidth = $_GET["winWidth"]; }
if(isset($_GET["winHeight"]) && $_GET["winHeight"] > 0) {   $winHeight = $_GET["winHeight"]; }
if(isset($_GET["a"])) {  $a = $_GET["a"]; }
```

UPDATE:

What about further security functions like:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

or

```
stripslashes()
```

?
Please Stackoverflow, show me the magic :)

Harry

Comment: unless your form has a few million fields, those ifs(), individually and collectively, will still only take a few microseconds at most to run.

Comment: its just an example, maybe scaling it up in imagination until even not wasting some time there gets intresting. (and the code is just an example, I'm looking for some general / good ways to solve such problems)

Comment: This will most likely not be the bottleneck of your application; don't optimize for the sake of optimization. Regarding POST vs GET the usage guidelines says that you should use GET for idempotent operations only whereas POST is used when the state may change after the operation.

Comment: "What about" is not a question. Also that database escaping topic has been covered ad nauseum.

Comment: Planning the project, using a design pattern like MVC, Using compression, Caching with memcache or to static html or even storing query results in a session, not doing complicated/long calculations on loop iterations, using relative paths for include files, not using 100's of echos ect will noticeably speed up a script.

Comment: If you are accessing the database, the delay even in the connection setup alone will massively dwarf any number of checks like that you are going to perform, concentrate on DB efficiency.

Comment: This is a classic case of microoptimization and premature optimization.  Don't do either.  It will only make your code harder to maintain than necessary, and won't gain you any real performance gains, your DB session is always going to take an order of magnitude or two more time to execute than your form validation.

Comment: You are optimizing too early. Once you've got working code that is going too slow for you, THEN profile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to check if something has been posted and whether it's a positive integer:

```
if (isset($_POST['field']) && ctype_digit($_POST['field']))
```

`mysql_real_escape_string` is incredibly slow, compared to `addslashes`. However, it's definitely more secure.

However, it's normally not necessary to worry about all this too much. We're talking about billionths of a second here.